# SSIS not working when called by a Job

Tags: mysql, ssis

I have a SSIS Package that basicaly sends data from MSSQL to MySQL. Locally it works properly, but when I deploy it to the server it does not.
Here's the error.

```
04/29/2014 11:56:00,JOBNAME,Error,1,SERVER,JOBNAME,STEP 1,,Executed as user: XXXXX. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.2500.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started:  11:56:00 a.m.  Error: 2014-04-29 11:56:01.27     Code: 0xC00291EC     Source: ANSI MODE Execute SQL Task     Description: Failed to acquire connection "to.mysql.odbc". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  11:56:00 a.m.  Finished: 11:56:01 a.m.  Elapsed:  0.359 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.,00:00:01,0,0,,,,0
```

I'm connecting to MySQL via ODBC driver 3.51. 
The Package is password encripted and the password was suplied when the `.dtsx` file was added in the job's step. Package is running using a proxy and everything is fine there since there's plenty of other jobs on the server.

Any hint? Thanks.

EDIT.

`ANSI MODE` is the name of the first block inside the SSIS Package. It executes something in the MySQL server. The connection it uses comes from the connection manager and it seems to be ok. The only weird thing I see in the connection is that the string doesn't show the password for the connection. But I think that's always been the case, it asks you to write it down in the dialog box.

Another piece of information: The package is loaded in a step using file system. So I look for the `.dtsx` file. Honestly, I'm not sure if it has something to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to make sure the ODBC is configured on the server and using a User Name and password and not windows authentication.

Answer (score 1):

If other jobs connecting to the server using the same account are working, likely the problem is that there is something wrong in how the ssis pacakage is configured. We have seen this type of thing where the server  role can only access the prod database buut the SSIS pacakage was hard coded for the local or the dev database instead of being correctly configured to go to the prod database.

Comment: How is it that the job can't acquire the mysql connection? Or what options could I check because the connection is there.

Comment: Check what database it is going to. If it is not going to a database the owner of teh job has, then it can't connect.

Comment: the database is explicited in the connection string. I have admin rights on the dev pc and also on the deploy server.

Comment: You should never use hard coded connections. You need to start using configurations. Your rights have nothing to do with the rights of the account running the job which should never be you personally but should be a general account (what if you left and they deleted your rights, all the jobs woudl fail)